# Call web Service by condition

Tags: .net, web-services

I am using 2 web service `RepoServe1` and `RepoServe2`

When a user login there's flag `isNew`

```
if(isNew)
{
  main.RepoServe1.RepoClient objClient = new main.RepoServe1.RepoClient(); 
}
else
{
  main.RepoServe2.RepoClient objClient = new main.RepoServe2.RepoClient(); 
}
main.RepoServe2.Customer objCusotmer = new main.RepoServe2.Customer();
objCusotmer  = objClient.GetData();
```

this is the ordinary way to call the service.

I want to make function that returns the ClientObject of service.

Anyone knows the way ??